# iOS: How to find user location without using Location Services?

Tags: ios, gps, cllocationmanager, gprs

Is there any alternative to get User location and do GeoFence rather than using Location Services in iOS. I am asking this because, when we enable Location Services, battery consumption is too high. That's why I am looking for an alternative. What can I try?

Comment: It's called region monitoring: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html  but it isn't very accurate ofcourse. There are certain conditions like you need to cross a boundary and stay there for 10 seconds or so before the system register that as a region crossing. Region monitoring uses less battery (since it's less accurate).

Comment: What techniques are you using to locate the user.  The WWDC videos and the Core Location programming guides provide advice on how to reduce battery impact - in particular, decrease the accuracy required, increasing the distance before you get an update and using the significant location change service

Answer (score 0):

If you are using map then, no need to implement location service code to capture current location, set YES to showUserLocation property of `MKMapView
 [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];` and implement its delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
```

`

```
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
[self.mapView setDelegate:self];
[self.mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[self.view addSubview:self.mapView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.viewLiveDrive];`
```

delegate :

```
    - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation{
    NSLog(@"Location Current : %@ ",userLocation.location);
    [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];
}
```

Now you can enjoy with current location  :)